# Best Syncing Databases across multiple platforms

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, winforms, postgresql

I am designing an application that will clients on windows, wed, driod, iOS, and windows phone.  I am in a conundrum about what is the best database to use and what is the best architecture approach to follow.

**First Thought**
Have a master DB that drives the website and every clients information, and having smaller light weight DBs on the client machines that sync with the master only the subset of information that is relevant to the subscribed user.  Meaning that if I am user 101 then my windows app, driod, iOS apps will only have my subset of data in the local DB which will give me the power to work offline, but when I am online I can sync with the master DB.

**Second Thought**
Giving every client their on DB on the server and then just having their independent OS's apps sync with their own DB's.  My thought behind this is that syncing less complex.

My goal is to do this in way that doesn't get bogged down with maintenance issues, will keeping the system flexible for growth.

All suggestions or questions would be great.
Also what DB's would be best?
Also what sync'ing technology would be best?

The website will be in Asp.net.
the windows app will be in .Net also.

Comment: This is really generalized and seems to be several different questions in one. Stack Overflow isn't a general discussion forum, so this'll probably get closed (and downvoted, though I haven't). Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: General thoughts: Two-way DB-to-DB sync is a nightmare, avoid it at all costs. It *might* be OK if you can assign one side to be the "winner" in all conflict resolutions and don't mind anomalies like deleted records re-appearing, but overall - avoid. I'd use a centralized DB and a web service.

Comment: Not sure I agree it is general, it is DB syncing Architecture question, Sorry if i dont know enough to be specific, but i was looking for some pointers form ppl who had experience.  I have done a good bit of research.  Can u point me in the direction of forum that discusses architecture?

Comment: thank you Craig i see what ur saying it has been 10 years since I have done live production replication.  and they were both SQL Server DB's

Comment: Replication is a *very* different job to syncing and working offline, where data can diverge and need merging. You *really* don't want to go there.

Comment: Thanks again Craig. I am new to this whole environment and trying to wrap my head around the complexities.

Comment: then keep it as *simple as possible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally create a central database and create web services to interface it. This way the device and software you use to connect only need to understand basic http messaging. NodeJS has a really nice PostgreSQL lib you could use along with a nodejs module called Express that would allow you to create routes to your database procedures. For example a call of http://myaddress.com/select_all_employees would route to a call that invokes the stored procedure that will select and return you all the employees in a json string or some other standard format.  Any device and it's development framework should be able to make that type of simple web call.

Comment: My answer assumes you don't need to be disconnected.

Comment: Also note you can also send parameters to Express routes.

Comment: Following that logic i would also be able to stack request to the centralized DB in an offline situation.  Meaning if any client is offline I can populate client DB and wait to process new inserts or updates when client goes back online

Comment: @ChampionChris What if the same client makes changes on the website directly from a computer while their phone is offline, then the phone syncs?

Comment: @ChampionChris I'm not sure that would be easy depending on your use case. To do an update assumes you have a local datastore of the data you want to update which would allow the user to update it and you to send the update to some kind of queue for to be later replicated aka replayed on the central server.  My hopes were you really didn't need to handle disconnected state.

Comment: @CraigRinger yes the phone would then sync.  The phone should be able to make a request for updates/records/transactions it doesn't have

Comment: @ChampionChris I think back to Craig Ringer's comment of avoid having to sync if at all possible. It's hard and messy to implement and maintain.  Do you really need to handle disconnected use cases?

Comment: @JustBob - Thats where my nightmare comes in at handling the disconnected state.  Im am seeing apps like Evernote handle it.  I have already started doing some reading on NodeJS.  Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @JustBob yeah the disconnected state is quite important especially because of the mobile aspect.  The app should be able to used where u have access to the internet or not.

Comment: @ChampionChris Nobody's saying multi-way sync/merge is impossible. It's just *hard*. And Evernote uses a web service. Seriously, if you're inexperienced at this *don't* look at multiway sync to start with.